# Can fluentd parse tzinfo timezones like "America/Chicago"?

Tags: timezone, fluentd

This seems like it should be straightforward, but if it is, I'm missing something.

I have log file which includes dates in this format:

`16-Jul-2019 10:47:05 America/Chicago`

To parse these, I'm using this format in my `<source>` block:

`time_format %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z`

However, as far as I can tell, this will only parse rfc822-compatible time zones. Although `America/Chicago` is valid in tzinfo, the resulting fluentd record has the timestamp `2019-07-16T10:47:05Z`. The timezone is ignored and the parsing falls back to local time (which is UTC on my server).

It's important that I parse the time zone because:

1. I need to automatically account for daylight saving offsets, and
2. For strange reasons that aren't relevant here, I can't rely on the specified time zone always being the same.

Unfortunately, I'm in a position where I can't control the log formatting at all.

Comment: Can you try provide [timezone](https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/parse-section#time-parameters)?. Example -  `timezone America/Chicago` and then you can remove `%Z` from `time_format`. Let me know if that works!!.

Comment: That would work if not for point #2 above. Not every log entry is in the same time zone. (I know that's kind of crazy, but it's out of my control.)